# Windows can't be installed, UEFI or Legacy Bootable USB Drive

Tags: windows, boot, usb

It seems that my laptop's partition table is causing headaches for me,my Windows installation has stopped at this point:

[image: Windows can't be installed]

As explanation,windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS.

My first effort was to create USB bootable stick with rufus, and now the second one with [iso2disc](https://www.top-password.com/blog/create-uefi-or-legacy-bootable-usb-drive-for-windows-10-setup/)

But again I have same problems.My laptop is with MBR partition type, it seems that as an obstacle.What should I try now?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to delete the partition?

Comment: No,but gparted Device option was not active.Should I try this from command line?

Comment: Delete both partitions right from the Windows setup screen you showed, then click next. Windows will build the partitions it needs itself.

Comment: FYI (and for future reference because you *will* face that issue), Windows strictly requires MBR for Legacy/CSM and GPT for UEFI. Unless when installing in old hardware with BIOS, **always** install in UEFI mode (with GPT). I even recommend disabling Legacy/CSM altogether at the firmware settings (UEFI) to avoid booting (and consequently install) in Legacy mode.